# whats the difference between string literals, and just a string?

Tags: javascript

I’m studying JavaScript and this is a statement I came across:

```
new String("Hello");
```

This will create a new string that is the same as string literal `"hello"`, although it will be classed as an object rather than a primitive values. For this reason it is preferable to use the string literal notation.

What is a String literal?

Why is `new String("Hello")` classed as `Object`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A literal string (or literal `<any data type>`) means that you just reference the data directly.

For example

```
"Hello".length // returns 5
```

The `"Hello"` is a string literal since we are just referencing it "as-is".
You could do exactly the same thing with a string object:

```
var strObj = new String("Hello");
strObj.length // returns 5
```

These two examples are pretty much identical (for the sake of this example). Both create a string variable and measure it's length.
The first uses a string literal and the second uses a string object.

---

Here is another example using numbers - if you do a direct calculation such as:

```
5 + 2
```

you'll be using number literals - again, when you only reference the data directly, it is considered a "literal".